# $.inArray is giving -1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be pretty straight forward:

HTML

```
<a href="url" id="thumba" data-id="26">my link</a>
<input type="hidden" id="pageids" value="28,27,26,17,18,19,">
```

Jquery

```
  var thumbaid = $('#thumba').data("id");
  // get position
    var itemids = $('#pageids').val(); 
    var itemids_array = itemids.split(',');
    var currentpos = $.inArray(thumbaid, itemids_array );
    alert(currentpos);
```

Gives me -1?

The funny thing is that if I replace " $(thumba).data("id")" for a number in the jquery code as "26", it works!

The result should be, in this case, "2".

Any ideas?

Comment: try  alert(thumbaid); and see what's coming

Comment: Try to use `console.log(...);` when debugging instead of `alert(...);` (when debugging in IE, open developer console first with `F12` key)

Comment: @rookieB Please don't recommend people towards `alert()` for debugging. That's what the console is there for.

Comment: Are you triggering your jQuery once the DOM you are trying to access is actually ready? If not, your `thumbaid` will be empty.

Comment: @oGeez I agree , but considering the code in the question , i suggested so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to convert the value to a string.

```
var thumbaid = $('#thumba').data("id").toString();
```

Why...? If you were to

```
console.log(itemids_array);
```

you would see this

```
["28", "27", "26", "17", "18", "19", ""]
```

They are not numbers, they are strings. See http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: **This** is indeed the way to handle data attributes, not like others suggested `.attr("data-id")`

Comment: James was already handling it correctly. Only one person threw a dodgy bone.

Comment: Thanks guys, most of you pointed to the String solution, and you were right! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `thumbaid` is a number, and the `itemids_array` contains strings. Try `var currentpos = $.inArray(thumbaid.toString(), itemids_array );`

jQuery's `data` function reads the `data-` attributes and parses digits to numbers.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's `data` function does things to the data it reads from the `data-*` attributes on initialization, including turning number-like strings into numbers. Since `$.inArray` does an `===` check, that's why it fails. You end up looking for the *number* 26 in an array of strings.

If you simply use `.attr("data-id")` instead, the conversion won't happen.

This behavior is documented in the [`data` docs](http://api.jquery.com/data):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is converted to the number 100.

If you're only using `data` to read `data-*` attributes, I recommend using `attr` instead to avoid this kind of thing, and to avoid the confusion caused by the fact that while `data` *initializes* from `data-*` attributes, it doesn't *write* to them when you set data. Of course, if you need to store data associated with elements and you don't want it on an attribute (because it's not string data, or you don't want it showing in the DOM inspector), `data` is the right tool for that job.

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working, is because jQuery data is returning an int not string.

See this example.

```
<a href="url" id="thumba" data-id="26">my link</a>
<input type="hidden" id="pageids" value="28,27,26,17,18,19,">
```

Javascript:

```
var thumbaid = $('#thumba').data('id').toString();

// get position
var itemids = $('#pageids').val(); 
var itemids_array = itemids.split(',');
console.log(itemids_array);
var currentpos = $.inArray(thumbaid, itemids_array );
console.log(currentpos);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$().data()` will convert the `data-*` attribute's value to a JavaScript value. In your case, `thumbaid` is converted to a number.

`$.inArray` compares elements using the strict equality operator(===). That is, `'26' === 26` returns false as no type coercion occurs.

From the [**jQuery.data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) docs:

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null). A value
>   is only converted to a number if doing so doesn't change the value's
>   representation. For example, "1E02" and "100.000" are equivalent as
>   numbers (numeric value 100) but converting them would alter their
>   representation so they are left as strings. The string value "100" is
>   converted to the number 100.